# Can't startup Bitgo on Windows

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-testnet

After installing bitgoJS, I cd into the bin directory and run the below command

```
bitgo-express --debug --port 3080 --env test --bind localhost
```

I got,

> 'bitgo-express' is not recognized as an internal or external command,